# How to manage distributed transaction co-ordination between webservice calls and database?

Tags: java, sap-ase, distributed-transactions

We have an external webservice which has exposed couple of APIs `lock` and `unlock`. The following are the steps followed while saving values in our system.

```
try 
  call lock
  save changes in single DB transaction
catch user_defined_exception
  call unlock
```

In case if there is any transaction timeout, we will not call `unlock` since this timeout exception is not considered to be part of user defined exceptions. Also in future, any new exceptions may be introduced , we dont want to include all those exceptions and do unlock. 
We are looking for any industrial standard/pattern to do transaction co-ordination between service and database transactions. 
Our application is built in `java` and the database is `Sybase ASE`. 
Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sybase is a company, not a database.  Which Sybase product are you referring to (ASE, ASA, IQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [recommended practice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) for correct locking with exceptions in Java is the following:

```
lock();
try {
  doStuff();
} finally {
  unlock();
}
```

This makes sure that the lock is released no matter what exception is thrown (or not), without the need to catch or re-throw it. However, this might still not be the safest thing to do in your case, since `unlock()` is a remote call and can itself throw exceptions.

The standard for coordination between services and databases is [WS-AT](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wsat-1.1-spec-os/wstx-wsat-1.1-spec-os.html). Any Java application server should support it, bridge with JTA, and with 2-phase commit on the database itself. When configuring the database connection in the application server, make sure you select the XADataSource option.

Comment: Actually I m expecting unlock to happen only if there is any exception. But your pseudo code will unlock though there is no exception at all. I ll try to explore your suggestion regarding WS-AT.